# Prove that $f(x)=x^2+1$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Using the limit definition, prove that $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2+1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ is continuous.

My attempt:

By the definition of continuity, a function is continuous if there exists a $\delta > 0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, and $|x-y| < \delta$.

It is given that $\epsilon < 0$, and I am going to set $\delta < 1$.
Thus, $|x-y| < 1$. Since $f(x) = x^2+1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ or $(x-c)(x+c)$, and $|x-y| < 1$, then it be true that $|(x-y)(x+y)|<|x+y|$ which would imply $-(x+y)<(x^2-y^2)<(x+y)$.

If we set $y=1$, then $-x-1 < x^2+1 < x+1-x < x^2 < x$. Since $x^2 < x$, then $x$ must be less than 1, $x < 1$.

Since $\delta$ was set as $\delta < 1$, and $x < 1$, then I am going to set $x=\delta$.

We are trying to prove that $|x-y| < \delta$, and $x=\delta$.
Therefore, $|\delta - y| < \delta$. Thus, $y < \delta$ in order for $|\delta - y| < \delta$ to be true.

Since $y < x$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<|f(x)|$
Since $|f(x)-f(y)| > 0,$

Then there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $0 < |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$
Will this prove that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2+1$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ by the definition of continuity?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to prove that f is continuous. Reading the wall of text under "My attempt" will show the steps that I have taken to prove this.

Comment: OK.  In the future, make sure you make clear what exactly your question is *before* jumping straight into your work.

Comment: Thanks for the critique of my question, were you planning on evaluating my attempt?

Comment: $x^2+1 \ne (x-1)(x+1)$